# postgreSql log file Errors

Tags: postgresql-9.4

My application is deployed on remote application server (Linux) and from there it tries to connect to DB server (PostgreSql 9.4) which is again present on another remote server (Linux). I send a long message to app server through JMS and this message processing takes many hours to get processed. But unfortunately I am getting facing some issues of performance with DB server. When I see postgresql.log file I can see the below errors/warning:

```
< 2017-05-05 09:18:00.676 CEST >LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection timed out

< 2017-05-05 13:38:33.704 CEST >LOG:  incomplete startup packet

< 2017-05-05 13:42:29.158 CEST >LOG:  unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction

< 2017-05-05 13:50:49.163 CEST >LOG:  checkpoints are occurring too frequently (1 second apart)
< 2017-05-05 13:50:49.163 CEST >HINT:  Consider increasing the configuration parameter "checkpoint_segments".
```

Do I need to update something in postgresql.conf file. Can somebody please advise what should I follow to avoid these errors?

Comment: You mean apart from the advices already given in the logfile?

Comment: Could you please advise what could be done for :
< 2017-05-05 09:18:00.676 CEST >LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection timed out

Comment: Does my DB Server is closing the connnection in between? Hence there is an error regarding 'Incomplete startup packet'?

Comment: Could anybody plese suggest on this?